# Updating Morphia/mongodb in production after refactor of object classes

Tags: java, mongodb, orm, morphia

My company uses mongodb connected to our java project with morphia for ORM stuff. Recently we've done some refactoring of our codebase and the package names have changed. Unfortunately,the rename of the packages has caused a problem with EXISTING databases. Because we have customers that are already in production, we can't really tell them to wipe their database and start over when we update the product.

I have tried two approaches. One was to write a script that updated all the entries with an old value for the className field to the correct values.
The other approach was to remove the className field from all the entries, and add the noClassnameStored annotation to the class.

Neither of these two approaches seemed to allow an existing database to load under the new version of our product. I am now thinking that perhaps the issue is with an embedded object that we use. Our "Job" class has a field called parameters that uses JobParameters as the class. We then populate the field with derived classes, (eg. MigrationJobParameters extends JobParameters). Both of those classes (as well as the JobParameters base class) use the "embedded" and "concreteClass=" annotations.
I've noticed morphia goes ahead and adds the className field to the database object, which kind of makes sense to me.

At the end of the day, Java throws an exception that it can't cast JobParameters to MigrationJobParameters, which again, kind of makes sense.

So my question is how can I update an existing database that contains embedded objects that have inheritance after the object's namespaces change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion turned out to be correct, the problem was that while entities don't need the className, embedded objects where the object is of type  require the object to have className so morphia can deserialize them to the proper class. So basically both approaches I tried were partially correct.

The solution is thus:

- The classes for entities should have the noClassnameStore annotation.
- The classes for embedded objects should have the concreteClass
  annotation.
- The update script should update the className field for
  those embedded objects that require it.
- The update script should remove all the className fields for everything else.